# Set axis tick and label to include maximum value on bar plot

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I am using base R to create multiple side-by-side bar plots (I prefer to avoid using `ggplot` because I am often limited in functionality). I find the result not visually pleasing because the axis ticks don't line up at all : sometimes the top of the axis is well below the maximum value and sometimes it is above. Is there a way to set it so that the final axis tick value includes the maximum value? It can't align perfectly because each graph has its own range and thus its own set of ticks values but I would like to at least have it so that the style is consistent across 12 graphs.

I am creating the series using a function (and a loop) so I would prefer an automated solution (rather than adjusting each graph with setting the maximum limit `axis()` separately)

Here is a simplified sample with the `iris` dataset. The issue that comes up is that the axis ends at 6 in the first panel, which is below the maximum value including error bars (7.2238), whereas in the second panel the axis ends above the maximum value.

```
library(vegan)
data(iris)

x1_mean<-tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=mean)
x1_sd<-tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=sd)


x2_mean<-tapply(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, FUN=mean)
x2_sd<-tapply(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, FUN=sd)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
br1=barplot(x1_mean, ylim=c(0, (max(x1_mean)+max(x1_sd))*1.1))
errbar(x = br1, y = x1_mean, 
                     yplus = x1_mean+x1_sd, 
                     yminus = x1_mean-x1_sd, add = T, cex = 0)


br2=barplot(x2_mean, ylim=c(0, (max(x2_mean)+max(x2_sd))*1.1))
errbar(x = br2, y = x2_mean, 
       yplus = x2_mean+x2_sd, 
       yminus = x2_mean-x2_sd, add = T, cex = 0)
```

[image]

EDIT/PROGRESS:

I have managed to extract the maximum value of the axis using `par("yaxp")` and used that to add an extra tick so that the last tick value is greater than the maximum value on the graph. But, it forces me to actually plot the default graph, which creates two graphs.
I've also included a simplified version of the function (using `iris` as a sample dataset) that I am trying to build, which will be perhaps clearer about my aims.

```
library(vegan)
data(iris)

barplot_adjust<- function(data, metric,...) {
  x_means<-tapply(data[,metric], list(data$Species), FUN=mean)
  x_sd<-tapply(data[,metric], list(data$Species), FUN=sd)
  br1 <- barplot(height = x_means, names.arg = names(x_sd), ylim = c(0, (max(x_means+x_sd))*1.1), 
                 main=metric, las=0,plot=TRUE,
                 ...)
   if( par("yaxp")[2]<(max(x_means+x_sd))*1.1 )
  {ymx=par("yaxp")[2]+par("yaxp")[2]/par("yaxp")[3]}else{ymx=par("yaxp")[2]}
  br1 <- barplot(height = x_means, names.arg = names(x_sd), ylim = c(0, ymx), 
                 main=metric, las=0,plot=TRUE,
                 ...)
  print(ymx)
  errbar(x = br1, y = x_means, yplus = x_means+x_sd, yminus = x_means-x_sd, add = T, cex = 0)
}

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
barplot_adjust(data=iris, metric="Sepal.Length")
barplot_adjust(data=iris, metric="Petal.Width")
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
library(vegan)
data(iris)

x1_mean<-tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=mean)
x1_sd<-tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=sd)
yl1 <- max((x1_mean + x1_sd))

x2_mean<-tapply(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, FUN=mean)
x2_sd<-tapply(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Species, FUN=sd)
yl2 <- max((x2_mean + x2_sd))


library(Hmisc)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
br1=barplot(x1_mean, ylim=c(0, (max(x1_mean)+max(x1_sd))), axes=FALSE)
axis(2, at=round(seq(0,yl1, length=5), 1))
errbar(x = br1, y = x1_mean, 
       yplus = x1_mean+x1_sd, 
       yminus = x1_mean-x1_sd, add = T, cex = 0)


br2=barplot(x2_mean, ylim=c(0, (max(x2_mean)+max(x2_sd))), axes=FALSE)
axis(2, at=round(seq(0,yl2, length=5), 1))
errbar(x = br2, y = x2_mean, 
       yplus = x2_mean+x2_sd, 
       yminus = x2_mean-x2_sd, add = T, cex = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: That seems like a good start but I liked R's automated split of the data into logical chunks (1, 2, 3, ...) and (0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, ... ). It must be possible to extract the axis values from barplot?

Answer (score 0):

Axes end at the maximum, the rest is actually a `box`. BTW, regarding the four `tapply`s, you may do them in one `aggregate`. (I use confidence intervals here that I think are [more appropriate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/218318/163114), but you can also use `sd()`)

```
FUN <- function(x) c(mean=mean(x), q=quantile(x, c(.025, .975)))
r <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, iris, FUN))
r <- t(`rownames<-`(r[-1], r[,1]))
```

If you like base R, you may want to use `arrows` instead of `Hmisc::errbar`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))  ## set par and store defaults
br1 <- barplot(r[1,], ylim=c(0, max(r[1:3,]))*1.1)
arrows(br1, y0=r[2,], y1=r[3,], code=3, angle=90, length=.05)
box()
br2 <- barplot(r[4,], ylim=c(0, max(r[4:6,]))*1.1)
arrows(br2, y0=r[5,], y1=r[6,], code=3, angle=90, length=.05)
box()
par(op)  ## restore par defaults
```

[image]

I'm not very sure what you mean by *"axis ticks don't line up"*, probably you want the same `ylim` for both graphs?

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
br1 <- barplot(r[1,], ylim=c(0, max(r))*1.1)
arrows(br1, y0=r[2,], y1=r[3,], code=3, angle=90, length=.05)
box()
br2 <- barplot(r[4,], ylim=c(0, max(r))*1.1)
arrows(br2, y0=r[5,], y1=r[6,], code=3, angle=90, length=.05)
box()
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: The axes *don't* end at the maximum value. That is precisely the behaviour that I WANT.  (I want the axes to end at a somewhat consistent point between the different graphs, not at the exact same limit). How can I set that? In my output, the axis stopped at 6 for the first panel whereas in your output the axis stopped at 8 (which is what I would want).

Comment: BTW, my actual data and graphs are based on a loop going through the attributes of my dataset and using standard error. I used a simplified version for the example here in the question because I thought it wouldn't change the main point.

Comment: @user3386170 What if you omit the `box()` line in each case?

Comment: I checked and the reason your output ends at 8 instead of 6 is that the maximum value using the 95% percentile is 7.7 instead of 7.2238 using `sd` so it tips over a threshold that the algorithm considers to include the 8 in the ticks. The `box()` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user3386170 Check the `ylim=` argument, there is a threshold where the axis switches from 6 to 8.